# How to automatically append gwt.codesvr to page URL

Tags: gwt, gwt-hosted-mode

When running a GWT application in hosted mode one usually needs to add the location of the code server in a query string parameter, for example instead of `index.html` one may need to open `index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997`. The problem is that `gwt.codesvr` is not usually included in hyperlinks, so it has to be added manually. Adding it to all links in your application does not seem a good idea as it will interfere with the final GWT-compiled version. Another option is for `index.html` to introspect itself by JavaScript and append a default `gwt.codesvr` to `window.location`, but this should be done only after the application is sure that it has not been compiled, that is after the `GWT module may need to be (re)compiled` alert. 
The ideal solution, I believe, would be for GWT to allow customization of the action it does after it finds no permutations to select from. The default action is to show the alert warning just mentioned, but unfortunately this is not customizable.

So my question is this: what is the best way to automatically open the current page with a default `gwt.codesvr` when there is no compiled permutations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm dealing with 'Places' all the time now I updated the bookmarklet to deal with '#' too.

```
javascript:(function(){h="localhost";p="9997";l="gwt.codesvr="+h+":"+p;s=false;if(document.location.href.indexOf("gwt.codesvr")<0){q=document.location.href.indexOf("?");if(q<0){q=document.location.href.indexOf("#");if(q>0){q=q-1}s=true}if(q<0&&!s){document.location.href=document.location.href+"?"+l}else%20if(q>=0&&!s){b=document.location.href.substr(0,q+1);e=document.location.href.substr(q+1);document.location.href=b+l+"&"+e}else{b=document.location.href.substr(0,q+1);if(q<0){e=""}else{e=document.location.href.substr(q+1)}document.location.href=b+"?"+l+e}}})();
```

**Update 2/7/2017-** There had been a typo in the script. Corrected it.

Comment: There is an error in your Javascript. Can you double-check you copied it right?

Answer (score 5):

I made a bookmarklet that I click to debug the current page:

```
javascript:window.location+=(window.location.href.indexOf('?')==-1?"?":"&")+"gwt.codesvr=localhost:9997"
```

but that doesn't account for the hash at the end, which you may not need anyway. That bookmarklet is about the only thing I use my bookmarks bar for...

Possibly worth pointing out that this can be used even with a production server, as long as you have roughly the same client code locally that that server was running.

Answer (score 0):

Since you'll be using that url only for development (and maybe few times for remote debugging), just bookmark http://127.0.0.1:8888/index.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 (or whatever port you use).

Comment: I don't think your solution is very different from adding gwt.codesvr by hand. Of course it is always possible to bookmark any link. Besides, I can think of situations where this is not so useful, for example when index.html is loaded as an iframe....

Comment: you just type that url once, to start the app, there's no need to modify any link in your application to support codesrv

Comment: The most frequent case: you have a logout link on the top of your page. It makes an HTTP request to some logout action URL and then is redirected to index.html. since index.html is secure, you are redirected to the login page and after you log in you can see index.html. This is the second time you are here at index.html, but this time with gwt.codesvr parameter stripped

Comment: good point. but i'd argue the redirect is not properly implemented because it strips down parameters.

Comment: well the outcome of logout actions are usually fixed, most of the times it is to app's main page. Do you imply that the logout action should try to guess the user's page where logout was clicked, by inspecting the Referer header or something like that?