# Detecting what &gwt.codesvr should be set to in non-gwt pages in a GWT/servlet app?

Tags: gwt, dev-mode

We have an application that is built exclusively in dev mode using the embedded jetty server that comes with GWT.  We also host on jetty.

There are a number of pages we use for development only to do things like simulate SSO requests, view emails that were sent through the system, and check what files are uploaded.

When we try to link from these pages into a GWT page the problem becomes that &gwt.codesvr=192.168.0.101:9997 is not included in the URL and we get the error message "GWT module 'YourApp' may need to be (re)compiled".  Obviously I can paste in "&gwt.codesvr=192.168.0.101:9997" manually but is very annoying.  Does anybody know of a way to detect you are in the embedded Jetty dev mode server and auto generate links to have the correct "&gwt.codesvr=192.168.0.101:9997" added on?

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9122167/970308

I've updated this bookmarklet. It isn't perfect, but makes it quick while developing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a Filter which will simply redirect you to an address with `&gwt.codesvr=192.168.0.101:9997` as soon as you navigate to the one of the "development pages". If codesvr parameter is specific for each developer, each developer will have to set it in some cookie and filter will simply take this value from cookie.